# why does this DoCmd.TransferText behave erratically?

Tags: vba, ms-access

Following our recent migration of several Access databases (with the .mdb extension) between data centres, we've observed that certain operations, such as running queries or loading data, are now slower. While this in itself is concerning, the following code below, previously functional in our old data centre, now behaves erratically:

```vb
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "tmpExport", FileName, hasfieldnames:=True
```

The error we encounter reads:

> Reserved error (-3034); there is no message for this error.

Regrettably, my online searches haven't provided a resolution.

- `tmpExport` is an Access query that is dynamically created and subsequently deleted in earlier steps in the code.
- `FileName` is dynamically generated, comprising a timestamp coupled IDs from the database.

Background:
The code mentioned is pivotal in generating CSV files in batches. Picture a scenario where a batch is designed to produce 4 files. Achieving this might necessitate running the code multiple times within the same session, perhaps necessitating 4 to 5 attempts. An initial run might yield two files before an error halts the process. A subsequent attempt may fare slightly better, producing three files before another error emerges. Intriguingly, after 4 or 5 attempts, all files in the batch usually get generated. This pattern hints at possible caching during file creation, but the exact mechanism remains elusive.

It's also worth noting that file size doesn't appear to be the underlying issue. Tests involving single-row files have equally been prone to errors. Moreover, upgrading to a newer version of Access (using the .accdb extension) hasn't rectified the problem.

While I haven't included the entire code for brevity, I can confirm that the `DoCmd.TransferText` command is the primary source of the errors – a command that functioned flawlessly in our previous data centre.

Any insights or suggestions to pinpoint and rectify this challenge would be immensely valuable.

Comment: Have you step-debugged. If you step through code will all iterations complete without error? Issue does not appear to be with code but network and therefore question is not appropriate for SO.

Comment: Does a local copy behave in the same way?

Comment: @June7, thank you for your response. I've conducted step-debugging, and it appears that the iterations do not complete successfully. When the code reaches the following line: "DoCmd.TransferText," I encounter this error: "Reserved error (-3034); there is no message associated with this error." It's possible that you are correct in suggesting that this could be a network-related issue rather than a problem with the code itself. However, I need to find out the precise nature of the issue, which is why I decided to seek help on the forum.

Comment: Thanks Sam, No, I have not tried with a local copy yet. I should try that next.